# C doesn't show code after entering it in console

Tags: c

I am currently doing college task to create a simple program using C, to enter and display prices of shirts in store. The problem is about that it doesn't show prices after I enter them in console. I don't really understand what is the problem, because my experience in coding on C ~1 week. Can anyone help with that? Thanks.

```
int main(void)
{
   float small = 0.0; 
   float medium = 0.0; 
   float large = 0.0;
   float total = 0.0;
   printf("Set Shirt Prices\n");
   printf("================\n");
   printf("Enter the price for a SMALL shirt: $");
   scanf("%f", &small);
   printf("Enter the price for a MEDIUM shirt: $");
   scanf("%f", &medium);
   printf("Enter the price for a LARGE shirt: $");
   scanf("%f\n", &large);
   printf("Shirt Store Price List\n");
   printf("======================\n");
   printf("SMALL : $%f\n", small);
   printf("MEDIUM : $%f\n", medium);
   printf("LARGE : $%f\n", large);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the console terminating? You might want to wait for user input at the end.

Comment: The newline character `\n` in the last `scanf` is causing `scanf` to wait for more input. After typing the prices, type `bye` and hit enter, and the prices should be displayed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string)

Comment: btw, to print only two digits after the decimal, instead of the default 6 digits, use `%.2f` instead of `%f`

Answer (score 4):

This line is problematic:

```
scanf("%f\n", &large);
```

It's expecting the user to type a float followed by additional text.
Change it to:

```
scanf("%f", &large);
```

And if want the end-of-line character, you can prepend it to the next statement.

```
printf("\nShirt Store Price List\n");
```